WAMP Server showing my webpage, but not any CSS styling
Im hosting a PHP application with WAMP server. It runs through a CloudFlare Tunnel and subdomain.
When I go to my subdomain URL, the login page for my webapp loads and displays, but none of the CSS is being applied.
I know it has something to do with my Virtual Hosts coding in WAMP, but i dont know how to correct the issue.
Apache Virtual Host
<VirtualHost *:7080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias firedog
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/firedog/html"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/firedog/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

My File Structure

The index.php file is located inside the html folder

Are there any errors showing in browser console?

How do you access your css? Where is it placed? Outsite of document root?
